# How can i re-use an initialized class in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to access a initialized class in the main application from other modules but don't know how to do it. 
Background: i want to update a dataframe with data during the whole execution in the main application.

I have to following application structure (this is an simplified version of the code in my application):

```
constraints
- test_function.py (separate module which should be able to update the initialized class in the main app)
functions
- helper.py (the class which contains the dataframe logic)
main.py (my main application code)
```

main.py:

```
import functions.helper
gotstats = functions.helper.GotStats()

gotstats.add(solver_stat='This is a test')
gotstats.add(type='This is a test Type!')

print(gotstats.result())

import constraints.test_function
constraints.test_function.test_function()
```

helper.py:

```
class GotStats(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('init() called')
        import pandas as pd
        self.df_got_statistieken = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SOLVER_STAT','TYPE','WAARDE','WAARDE_TEKST','LOWER_BOUND','UPPER_BOUND','OPTIMALISATIE_ID','GUROBI_ID'])

    def add(self,solver_stat=None,type=None,waarde=None,waarde_tekst=None,lower_bound=None,upper_bound=None,optimalisatie_id=None,gurobi_id=None):
        print('add() called')
        self.df_got_statistieken = self.df_got_statistieken.append({'SOLVER_STAT': solver_stat,'TYPE': type, 'WAARDE': waarde, 'OPTIMALISATIE_ID': optimalisatie_id, 'GUROBI_ID': gurobi_id}, ignore_index=True)

    def result(self):
        print('result() called')
        df_got_statistieken = self.df_got_statistieken
        return df_got_statistieken
```

test_function.py:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

def test_function():
    import functions.helper
    gotstats = functions.helper.GotStats()
    gotstats.add(solver_stat='This is a test from the seperate module')
    gotstats.add(type='This is a test type from the seperate module!')
    print(gotstats.result())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_function()
```

In main i initialize the class with "gotstats = functions.helper.GotStats()". After that i can correctly use its functions and add dataframe rows by using the add function.
I would like that test_function() is able to add dataframe rows to that same object but i don't know how to do this (in current code the test_function.py just creates a new class in it's local namespace which i don't want). Do i need to extend the class object with an function to get the active one (like logging.getLogger(**name**))?

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `test_function` accept the instance as a parameter and pass it to the function when you call it:

main.py:

```
import functions.helper
from constraints.test_function import test_function


gotstats = functions.helper.GotStats()
gotstats.add(solver_stat='This is a test')
gotstats.add(type='This is a test Type!')

print(gotstats.result())

test_function(gotstats)
```

test_function.py:

```
import sys, os
import functions.helper

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())


def test_function(gotstats=None):
    if gotstats is None:
        gotstats = functions.helper.GotStats()

    gotstats.add(solver_stat='This is a test from the seperate module')
    gotstats.add(type='This is a test type from the seperate module!')
    print(gotstats.result())
```

Comment: Yes this works, thanks. But i have to say, it somewhat feels like there should be another way in stead of passing complete functions trough other functions? But maybe i'm wrong.... Something like how the logger function in Python works?

Comment: @SanderdeWildt Where do we "pass complete function through other functions"?

Comment: Calling functions from other functions is actually a pretty normal thing. In fact, this is the main reason why we have functions at all :)

Comment: I was talking about "test_function(gotstats)" in main.py where we pass the initialized gotstats to the function. But yes, i was just thinking the wrong way... I thought when you do it this way, you have to return something as well. But apparently you can just fire gotstats.result somewhere at the end of the main.py and it will just contain the added df rows wherever they were added, great thanks!